# SQL Report Services on AOAVG

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, report

We have 2 SQL Servers in a SQL Server 2016 AOAVG.  When we fail over to the secondary replica, the reports do not work.  Am I right in thinking that this is because we need to stop the SQL Server agent on the primary and then restart the ReportServices service on the secondary?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your SSRS pointing to the LISTENER? if no probably your SSRS is pointing to the now-secondary node.
Are your report data sources pointing to the listener? if no probably your reports are pointing to the now-secondary node, maybe not readable.

Do you have ssrs jobs in your sql server agent? If yes, you have to restart ssrs for refreshing/creating them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  SSRS looks at the listener.  I've done a bit more looking around and I believe you're correct - SSRS needs to be restarted after a failover event.  I am going to test this as well to make sure it is this for my issue.

Comment: ok i build a more readble answer

Comment: SSRS service needs to be restarted every time failover so SQL server subscription jobs will get recreated on new primary.  Please check below link. https://jbswiki.com/2017/09/06/reporting-services-using-alwayson-availability-group/

Comment: I did some testing at the back end of last week - everything points at the AVG listener, and when I run the reports they work correctly.  I do not need to restart any services.  Thanks everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your SSRS is pointing to the listener and not to the now-secondary node.

Please check if your reports are pointing to the listener and not to the now-secondary node.

And Yes, you have to restart ssrs for refreshing/creating ssrs jobs in your sql server agent.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below article. The second part of this article is about configurring SSRS to work with AlwaysOn, make sure that you have it configured correctly. Like mentioned by MBuschi SSRS should point to the listener and reporting databases should be joined to AG.

https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-sql-server-reporting-services-databases-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/